# Functions with multidimensional codomain

Tags: functions

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^L$, where $L>1$. For each $x\in \mathbb{R}^K$, let $x_i$ denote the $i$-th element of $x$.

I have some terminology/definitional questions:

1. Is $f$ a function or has it another more formal name?
2. Suppose that $L=3$ and for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^K$, $f(x)=(\sum_{k=1}^K x_k, x_1-x_2, x_K+\infty)$. Is it correct to say that $f$ is linear? In other words, when can $f: \mathbb{R}^K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^L$  be called linear for $L>1$?

Comment: A function is a relation over two sets that associates to every element of the first set _exactly one_ element of the second set. So in your example, $\mathbb{R}^K$ is the first set and $\mathbb{R}^L$ is the second, but without more details we cant know if it is a _function_ or a different kind of _relation_. A linear function is a pretty broad definition. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Thanks. With regards to question 2., what I mean by linear (but I don't know if that is correct) is that each component of the $L\times 1$ vector $f(x)$  is a linear function of $x$. Is it a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, $f$ is a function. Formally, any instance of a mapping from one set to another such that a) $x=y\implies f(x)=f(y)$, b) for all $x$ in the domain, $f(x)$ is in the codomain, is a function.
2. The term "linear" has different meanings in different contexts. The function you describe is linear in the sense that it preserves scalar multiplication (i.e. $af(\mathbf{x})=f(a\mathbf{x})$, and vector addition $f(\mathbf{x})+f(\mathbf{y})=f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})$. The components are likewise linear.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused on 2. First, let me address my first mistake and define $f: \mathbb{R}^K\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}^L$ where $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line. Now, take my function $f: \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ where $f(x_1,...,x_K)$ is the $3\times 1$ vector $(\sum_{k=1}^K x_k, x_1-x_2, x_K+\infty)$. Why do I need $K=3$ here? Is $f$ now linear (in the sense that each component of the $3\times 1$ vector $f(x_1,...,x_K)$ is a linear function of $(x_1,...,x_K)$)?

Comment: You do not need $K=3$, I misread the question.